# Combine Latest - same observable returning different values

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable

How to return different values from the same observable without multiple calls? I intend to subscribe just one time the firstObs$, but return the values and sumFromValues.

```
combineLatest([
            this.firstObs$,
            this.firstObs$.pipe(
                switchMap(someOperation => {
                       return this.observableSumOperation(someOperation.first, someOperation.second)
                })
            ),
          
            this.anotherObservable$,
        ])
          .subscribe(([values, sumFromValues, anotherValues]) => {
            }
```

Comment: "How to return different values from the same observable without multiple calls" `share` is what you're looking for. But really you only need only `firstObs$` once. The switchMap you've used doesn't have any observable in the inner stream. Just pass firstObs and in the subscribe you can compute what you were doing in the switchMap.

Comment: @maxime1992 and if the the switchMap have an observable in the inner stream?

Comment: Please make a minimal reproduction on stackblitz with mocked data. Then I'll be able to help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you've noticed, when you include the same source observable inside of `combineLatest`, the "combinelatest observable" will emit multiple times.  Generally this is not desirable.

I can think of two solutions for this:

1. use `debounceTime(0)` to suppress emissions that occur in the same event loop:

```js
combineLatest([
  firstObs$,
  firstObs$.pipe(map(({first, second}) => first + second)),
  anotherObservable$,
])
.pipe(debounceTime(0));
```

2. only include each source once inside of `combineLatest` and use `map` to build a new array/object that includes your derived value:

```js
combineLatest([
  firstObs$,
  anotherObservable$,
])
.pipe(
  map(([values, anotherValues]) => [
    values,
    values.first + values.second,
    anotherValues
  ])
);
```

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-76404875?devtoolsheight=100&file=index.ts) that shows the problem and solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't specify what `anotherObservable` contains and how it behaves its hard to say how to best combine the values. But one idea is to split the combination of observables into two steps:

1. Map the `firstObs$` result together with `observableSumOperation`

```
const calculated$ = this.firstObs$.pipe(
      mergeMap((values) =>
        this.observableSumOperation(values.first, values.second).pipe(
          map((sum) => ({ ...values, sum })),
        ),
      ),
    )
```

2. Combine `calculated$`with `anotherObservable$`:

```
 combineLatest([calculated$, this.anotherObservable$]).subscribe(
      ([values, anotherValues]) => {
        const { first, second, sum } = values
      },
    )
```

Note that `combineLatest` will only fire as soon as **every** observable emits at least once. So if `anotherObservable$` does not emit a value, you will not enter the subscribe method